# Native alarm clock notification on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm currently deploying an app for iPhone and I was wondering if the app could receive a notification (while it is suspended in the background) when the alarm of the native clock rings so the app can be triggered to the foreground. If this is not possible is there any way to retrieve information about the shceduled time and date of the native alarm clock. I have been searching this on internet a lot but I couldn't find any answer on this question. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Really doubt Apple would allow it - think about it for a second - an alarm goes off and when user picks up the phone, some other app has opened *without any user interaction*. That's not good, is it?

Comment: looking for the same thing as you from 2012 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542048/native-alarm-clock-notification-on-ios - just being notified of clock events without ability to push to foreground would do as well, but the lack of it in 2016 is an example of Android superiority :(